# Assign onclick function to href dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am creating an anchor dynamically using jQuery by this method

```
var risk_delete = $('<a />', {
                                'id'    : 'delete_mitigator_'+increased_risk,
                                'name'  : 'delete_mitigator[]',
                                'href'  : 'javascript:void(0)',
                                'text'  : ''
                });
```

How can I assign onclick function in this strip of code?

Answer (score 2):

Just add click handler.

```
var risk_delete = $('<a />', {
    'id': 'delete_mitigator_' + increased_risk,
    'name': 'delete_mitigator[]',
    'href': 'javascript:void(0)',
    'text': ''
}).on('click', function() {
    //Your code
});
```

Comment: Can't i assign it inside the parameters along with name and text?

Comment: Typically it's considered bad practice to put your javascript logic in your html markup.  You want to keep your markup and business logic separate.

Comment: @Satpal, are you sure this will work if the element has not been appended to the DOM yet? I mean, trying to attach the handler before the object is appended to the dom?

Comment: @AmmarCSE, Yes it will, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/af8ek6rh/

Comment: @Saswat, _Can't i assign it inside the parameters along with name and text?_ Yes you can but will not recommend it. an example http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2zd87zra/

Comment: @Satpal, what will be the error, if i use it inside? and how can i set a name for the function, instead of writing the function body there?

Comment: @Saswat, No error, If you already have function defined simply use `'click': YouFunctionName`

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your hyperlink you can assign an onclick event handler just by using `.on()` delegate function:

```
var risk_delete = $('<a />', {
    'id'    : 'delete_mitigator_'+increased_risk,
    'name'  : 'delete_mitigator[]',
    'href'  : 'javascript:void(0)',
    'text'  : ''
});
```

**Click event:**

```
risk_delete.on( "click", function() {
  //Todo
});
```